# Microsoft Graph API - Create user in Azure AD B2C with local account identity gives Request_ResourceNotFound error

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

My goal is to create a local account, like `michele@gmail.com`, in **Azure Active Directory B2C**.

I want to use my own UI, so I started to look at how to implement the API. After some research, it looks like the best way to do it should be via Microsoft Graph.

I started by following [Manage Azure AD B2C user accounts with Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-accounts-graph-api), and I properly created an app (not sure if I need to choose the third options, but looks like the broader one):

[image]

with the following permissions (updated following also @Tony Ju screenshot):

[image]

Then I created the client secret and coded my own [auth provider](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/blob/dev/docs/CustomAuthenticationProvider.md)

```js
const { AuthenticationContext } = require('adal-node');

class AuthProvider {

    async getAccessToken() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const tenant = 'tenant';
            const authority = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenant}`;

            const authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

            const resource = 'https://graph.microsoft.com';
            const clientId = 'clientId';
            const clientSecret = 'clientSecret';

            authenticationContext.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(
                resource,
                clientId,
                clientSecret,
                (err, tokenResponse) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error('error!', err);
                        return reject(err);
                    }
                    return resolve(tokenResponse.accessToken);
                },
            );
        });
    }
}
```

and initialized the client

```js
require('isomorphic-fetch'); //needed for server side request with the client
const { Client } = require('@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client');

const options = {
    authProvider: new AuthProvider(),
};
const client = Client.initWithMiddleware(options);
```

[Following the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-create-a-user-with-social-and-local-account-identities), I create a local account

```js
const user = {
    displayName: 'John Smith',
    identities: [
        {
            signInType: 'emailAddress',
            issuer: 'MY_ISSUER.onmicrosoft.com',
            issuerAssignedId: 'jsmith@yahoo.com',
        },
    ],
    passwordProfile: {
        password: 'df42bfe2-8060-411f-b277-06b819874573',
    },
    passwordPolicies: 'DisablePasswordExpiration',
};

client
    .api('/users')
    .post(user)
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(e => console.error(e))
```

And I get back this "Request_ResourceNotFound" error

```js
GraphError {
  statusCode: 404,
  code: 'Request_ResourceNotFound',
  message:
   'Resource \'User_30140fa1-ae7e-40b7-ad5a-ef4d0b4cd4dc\' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.',
  requestId: 'fbf4c987-0383-472a-bc22-c94f98710344',
  date: 2020-05-18T13:19:14.000Z,
  body:
   '{"code":"Request_ResourceNotFound","message":"Resource \'User_30140fa1-ae7e-40b7-ad5a-ef4d0b4cd4dc\' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.","innerError":{"request-id":"fbf4c987-0383-472a-bc22-c94f98710344","date":"2020-05-18T15:19:14"}}' }
```

The error does not help and I don't know how to continue. The basic configuration looks correct, because I'm able to get all the users and also [create a user in the same tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-1-create-a-user).

What am I missing? Feels so weird having this type of error by following the official docs. I'm starting to think that I need to use the invitation API, but I just want to create a user and don't go into the full email verification flow. Plus, what I exactly need is in the official docs and I would expect it to work. So maybe there is just something wrong on my side.

Comment: Not sure if it's the reason: your code has some necessary ",". Try with this `const user = {
        displayName: 'John Smith',
        identities: [
            {
                signInType: 'emailAddress',
                issuer: 'MY_ISSUER.onmicrosoft.com',
                issuerAssignedId: 'jsmith@yahoo.com'
            }
        ],
        passwordProfile: {
            password: 'df42bfe2-8060-411f-b277-06b819874573'
        },
        passwordPolicies: 'DisablePasswordExpiration'
    };`

Comment: it does not make a difference, but thanks for the double check!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works perfectly. I only updated **tenant**,**clientId**,**clientSecret** and **MY_ISSUER** in your code. Here is the whole code I ran.

```
const { AuthenticationContext } = require('adal-node');
class AuthProvider {
    async getAccessToken() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const tenant = '6b72a356-867d-4c35-bde6-959d99388ca8';
            const authority = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenant}`;

            const authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

            const resource = 'https://graph.microsoft.com';
            const clientId = '270408b5-85a6-4e99-861e-7634853a5827';
            const clientSecret = 'VYD_F_Rr~eHYqLtTXqa1~1KRS_932yNw35';

            authenticationContext.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(
                resource,
                clientId,
                clientSecret,
                (err, tokenResponse) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error('error!', err);
                        return reject(err);
                    }
                    return resolve(tokenResponse.accessToken);
                },
            );
        });
    }
}
require('isomorphic-fetch'); //needed for server side request with the client
const { Client } = require('@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client');

const options = {
    authProvider: new AuthProvider(),
};
const client = Client.initWithMiddleware(options);

const user = {
    displayName: 'John Smith',
    identities: [
        {
            signInType: 'emailAddress',
            issuer: 'tonyb2ctest.onmicrosoft.com',
            issuerAssignedId: 'jsmith4@yahoo.com',
        },
    ],
    passwordProfile: {
        password: 'df42bfe2-8060-411f-b277-06b819874573',
    },
    passwordPolicies: 'DisablePasswordExpiration',
};

client
    .api('/users')
    .post(user)
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(e => console.error(e))
```

**The result:**

[image]

I registered an application under Azure Active Directory and granted **Directory.ReadWrite.All** permission.

[image]

[image]

Comment: hey Tony, thanks for the help! I'm using Azure AD B2C, can you try it?

Comment: @michelepatrassi Yes, it is B2C tenant, but you need to register the application in AAD. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-get-started?tabs=applications

Comment: in this step https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-get-started?tabs=applications#register-management-application I followed the "App Registration (preview)" option. Did you choose the first? Maybe the difference is there and something is wrong with the preview then

Comment: @michelepatrassi I also tried the second one(preview), it also works, can you check your steps again?

Comment: I created another azure B2C app, given the broader supported account type (I always picked the first option in the past), generate a new secret, and gave permissions (same as yours, plus the user one). Same result, I also added more screenshots :/ At this point maybe there is something wrong in the tenant itself? I want to profile the HTTP request to see if I can find out something

Comment: @michelepatrassi Not sure if the tenant itself has something wrong, you can try my configurations, updated the real values in the answer. I will delete the secret after your test. And capturing the http request is a good choice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214245/discussion-between-michelepatrassi-and-tony-ju).

Comment: I created a personal account with a b2c tenant from scratch and it just worked, so something has been changed in the tenant. The code by itself is fine. For my test, I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=app-reg-preview